# Database Query into Associative Array using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to grab data from my database and place in a format so I can call field1 and return field2.

In my mind I think this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $aa = $row["field1"];
    $bb = $row["field2"];
}

$cc = array(“$aa”=>”$bb”);
```

Will compute this:

```
$cc = array(
    "Row1a"=>"Stuff in field2 row1b",
    "Row2a"=>"Stuff in field2 Row2b",
    "Row3a"=>"Stuff in field2 Row3b",
    "Row4a"=>"Stuff in field2 Row4b",
    );
```

After this I will be able to:

```
echo $cc('Row1a');
```

To display:

```
Stuff in field2 row1b
```

Comment: `$cc` is overwritten each time through the loop so you end up with only the last row fetched.

Comment: That makes sense thank you Jay.  I think I may need to be a bit more thorough in my question.  How can the (top) array in the while() function as the the associative array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. If there aren't an even number of elements in `$row` then the odd last one will be set to `Last`.  But obviously this overwrites `$result` each time so you probably want a multidimensional array using a counter and `$result[$i]` or some such:

```
foreach(array_chunk($row, 2) as $pair) {
    if(isset($pair[0], $pair[1])) {
        $result[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
    }
}
if(isset($pair[0])) {
    $result['Last'] = $pair[0];
}
```

Comment: Will this allow me to cycle through my db and return the values in the format of an associative array?

Comment: You need to give an example of what you want the result to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and let me know if it meets your requirements

```
<?php

$result=NULL;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $aa = $row["field1"];
    $bb = $row["field2"];
    $result[$aa]=$bb;
}

echo $result['Row1a'];

?>
```

Edited code 
Then this should meet your requirement

```
<?php
$search=$_POST['userText'];
$query= "SELECT  * FROM table WHERE field1='".$search."';";

$result=mysql_query($query,$con);
$output=NULL;
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) //to check if at least 1 match found
{
    $array=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $output=$array['field2'];
}
if(isset($output))
    echo $output; // can be returned as needed
else
    echo 'No match found'; 

?>
```

Comment: Tried this, but the only thing that showed up was ARRAY x10.

Comment: Please provide some data format. like table and fields, just to clear up

Comment: I want to be able to get text from a form. Check to see if it matches any of the text in the database field 1 row 3  and if it is,  I want to be able to return/echo the data content from field 2 row 3.  Is this possible?